# Windows has MS Word. What does Mac have as a word processor?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, word-processor

Microsoft has MS Word as a word processor for Windows.

What does Apple have for macOS? I'd like same feature rich application MS Word offers.

Comment: I’m going to down vote this since it begs the question of requirements. Apple clearly has pages and Word clearly supports macOS. How will this be useful to others or answerable without some clarity on what feature rich means specifically.

Answer (score 13):

Unless I’m missing something, Microsoft Word is also available for macOS. For more information, visit [Welcome to the new Office for Mac!](https://products.office.com/en/mac/microsoft-office-for-mac).

If you’re looking for Apple's main word processor then Pages has most of the commonly used features of MS Word. It's free from the [Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/app/pages/id409201541?mt=12). For more information on Pages generally, visit [Create and collaborate on documents that are beautiful beyond words.](https://www.apple.com/pages/)

A couple of other options are [OpenOffice](https://www.openoffice.org/porting/mac/faq/installing/ooo.html) and [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org) (both free). There's also [NeoOffice](https://www.neooffice.org/neojava/en/index.php) (which does have a small cost but offers a number of improvements over OpenOffice and LibreOffice).

As an aside, if you’re interested in a bit of history, Microsoft Word was originally available for the Mac before it was available for Windows. More specifically, it was available for Mac in 1985, four years prior to the release of the Windows version in 1989.

If your boss or professor (or other person grading your work) uses Word, then using Word yourself can help avoid grief from possible compatibility issues that can arise when other apps export to Word format.

Comment: [Office Online](https://products.office.com/en-US/office-online/documents-spreadsheets-presentations-office-online) is available free as well.

Comment: There is also NeoOffice developed specifically for the Mac. its located here: https://www.neooffice.org/neojava/en/index.php. It has a suite of tools like a spreadsheet and presentation package.

Comment: @jmh Thanks for the reminder! I've added NeoOffice to my answer. :)

Comment: If 100% compatability is required Microsoft Word is a very nice program.

Answer (score 3):

There is Nisus Writer Express for light to medium use, and Nisus Writer Pro, if you are a professional writer, scholar, etc. at [Nisus.com](https://www.nisus.com/). Same engine, saves to RTF by default and both are *very* fast.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has (for free) the programs Pages, Numbers, and Keynote.  They are essentially Apple's take on Word (word processing), Excel (spreadsheets), and PowerPoint (presentations).  They can be found in the App Store and Pages is very feature rich and inter operates well with Word documents, rtf files and has online collaborative and web editing as well as iCloud document syncing integrated.

Word / Office 2016 is available for macOS as well, which can be purchased from Microsoft or many other sites.

Comment: downvoted... why?

Comment: Most probably because you poorly repeated an existing answer without adding anything.

Comment: Pages: about as good as Word—Numbers: sucks compared to Excel—Keynote: WAY better than Powerpoint, but that's not a very high bar to clear.

Comment: This is an amazing answer and correct. The question is soft since it doesn’t say anything about what features make a program rich. Let’s down vote a bad question and not vote down people with proper answers. I’ll probably bounty this answer if the down votes don’t change in time.

Comment: I would consider you to reconsider your votes @SolarMike everyone with a proper answer should get up votes and the question here is the problem for being vague and soft on requirements.

Comment: @bmike I explained the posible reason for downvotes, but I don’t think I did vote...

Comment: Apologies for assuming it was you @SolarMike I should have qualified if you had voted.

Comment: @SolarMike My straightforward answer provided information that was not in the "upvoted best" at the time, which was then edited afterwards.  It's this kind of pedantic nonsense that makes people not want to contribute at all.

Comment: @Hefewe1zen I read the first answer before you contributed, but do not assume I downvoted AND do not **Hate** on me just because I gave a possible explanation for the downvotes you received.

Answer (score 1):

WPS Office for Mac, it's still in beta but good to use. ANd it is free.
You can download it here:
http://www.wps.cn/product/wpsmac/